# Averiguar qué se recibe y de qué tipo es en una página php

Tags: php, variables, variables-globales

Creo que es una pregunta relativamente simple pero, no he logrado nada por ahora.

Tengo una página php que va a recibir información, pero desconozco qué información va a llegar, ni en qué formato.. nada, no dispongo de esa info pero debo recoger todo lo que entre para poder tratarlo.

Hay manera?

He probado con $_GET pero me devuelve un array vacío. Mismo caso para $_POST
Con $_SERVER sí obtengo información pero obviamente no es nada relativo a lo que entra ya que haciendo una prueba en la url y añadiendo parámetros, $_GET sí lo recoje pero $_SERVER no, por lo que tampoco recogería nada de los datos que espero.

Como tampoco sé en qué momento van a llegar los datos, la idea es capturar todo lo que "cargue" la web y enviarmelo por email para desde ahí poder reprogramar y recogerlo bien para su tratamiento.

Comment: Llega desde un formulario o como es que el usuario ingresa y manda esa info?

Comment: Es un servicio de una web, pero en la documentación no dice absolutamente nada de qué información mandan ni del formato. He descubierto webhooks.site, una web donde me facilitan una url única que yo puedo configurar en el servicio que me manda la info para que la mande a ese sitio y ahí puedo ver qué llega. Estoy probándolo ahora a ver si hay suerte

Comment: [`$_SERVER`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php) es una superglobal amplia, que puedes usar para obtener información sobre la URL, por ejemplo mediante `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];`, podrías usar también `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]`. Puedes hacer un `print_r($_SERVER);` y verificar si esta superglobal tiene lo que buscas ... Leyendo lo que comentas, podrías redirigir todo vía `.htaccess` a un archivo `index.php` y desde él controlar todas las peticiones que sean hechas a esa ruta. Y, si lo que quieres es contar visitas o algo así, te recomendaría Google Analytics.

Comment: Puedes intentar obteniendo lo que lea de `php://input` que generalmente es la data enviada por POST (ej: `file_get_contents("php://input")`)

Comment: He probado con lo que dices @F.Igor pero no entra nada, o no lo captura al menos.

Comment: @A.Cedano la variable $_SERVER la conozco, he revisado de nuevo por si me había dejado algo por ver pero no es el caso, no me devuelve nada de información útil (gracias igualmente)

Comment: Es raro que `$_SERVER` no te devuelva nada. ¿Desde dónde se accede al servidor, vía navegador/url o es desde alguna aplicación u otro entorno?

Comment: En una web de trading se genera una alarma que yo he configurado. El aviso te dan la opción de que se mande a un webhook. En este campo yo pongo mi archivo php y es lo que quiero ver. Por fin he encontrado en la documentación un sitio donde dice que se manda un json básico tipo {"id": "xxxx", "text":"yyyy"} pero con un $json = file_get_contents('php://input'); ///
$data = json_decode($json); /// mail("xxxx", "hey", "id= ".$data['id']); cuando llega el email, solo llega con "id=", sin valor